# What playable races are there with insect-like features besides Thri-Kreen?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, races

In the recent Spelljammer book releases for D&D 5e, there is the option of playing a race with "insectile features", i.e. Thri-Kreen. (AAG, p.15)

I want to know what - if any - other official races with insect-like features, other than the Thri-Kreen, have been playable in previous D&D editions.

Comment: Given that we've been accepting other forms of list question, I don't see a reason to close this one. From review.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**[Dromites](https://srd.dndtools.org/srd/races/racesPsionic.html#dromites)** from the 3.5 Expanded Psionics Handbook is a psionic race "called bug-men by the ignorant".

**[Diopsids](https://srd.dndtools.org/srd/races/racesDc.html#diopsids)** from the 3.5 Dragon Compendium is beetle-like race in the Underdark.

**[Insectare](https://srd.dndtools.org/srd/races/racesDramag.html#insectare)** from Dragon Magazine are "part elven, part insectoid".

I prefer not to discuss the **[Khepri](https://srd.dndtools.org/srd/races/racesDramag.html#khepri)**.

**[Xixchil](https://spelljammer.fandom.com/wiki/Xixchil)** from the AD&D MC9 Monstrous Compendium Spelljammer Appendix II are basically green Thri-Kreen with a penchant for body modification.

**[Chitines](https://srd.dndtools.org/srd/races/racesUnd.html#chitines)** from 3.x Monsters of Faerûn are not exactly insectile, but rather spider-like.

Of course, this list is probably not complete. And "insect-like features" is a rather subjective standard, so I imagine for instance the **[Xephs](https://srd.dndtools.org/srd/races/racesPsionic.html#xephs)** could be considered to have "insect-like" eyes.

Comment: thank you, this is really helpful. I also think "insect-like" has a vagueness to it. Would it be better if I update my question to "insectile" and stick to that as it appears in the description of Thri-Kreen for 5e?

Comment: @Senmurv No, no worries - if you're looking for "insect-like features", that's what you're looking for. It sounds like a matter of looking for a race to fit a concept, so the current question works well for that. The word "insectile" doesn't appear in the 3.5 Thri-Kreen description, so looking for that might narrow the search too much for your use-case.